# Where to create new storage account

Tags: azure-table-storage

last year i had successfully tested storage tables , 
now i need to create a new storage account in Azure.
But , It looks like now only blob container is supported .
How to create storage table accounts please ?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general server/hosting tech support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your storage account is in ZRS mode, only block blob is enabled, it is supported only in versions 2014-02-14 and later, Refer to [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-redundancy/) for more information. The replication setting for a storage accounts using ZRS can't be changed. We could find this information at Azure portal:
[image]

So I would suggest you try Tamra said, create a new Azure storage, with general-purpose, and do not choose ZRS replication. If you want to move files from old account storage to new Azure storage, please consider to use [AzCopy](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-azcopy/).

Answer (score 0):

you can create an Azure storage account that includes tables by creating a "general-purpose" storage account.

In the Azure Portal, choose New -> Data and Storage -> Storage Account. "General purpose" is the default type of storage account. Select this option to create a storage account that includes tables as well as blobs, queues, and files.

Answer (score 0):

I found that using ZRS replication is disabling tables, queues and files